# Python - make non-unique items in list unique by adding count

Tags: python, list, count, unique

How would I make the items in my list unique by concatenating a count, starting from 1 for each unique value?

so, for example:

`sheep, sheep, tiger, sheep, hippo, tiger`

becomes:

`sheep1, sheep2, tiger1, sheep3, hippo1, tiger2`

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) function from the collection package, I believe this will help you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could use Counter to do it.

```
from collections import Counter

s = ["sheep", "sheep", "tiger", "sheep", "hippo", "tiger"]
u = [ f"{a}{c[a]}" for c in [Counter()] for a in s if [c.update([a])] ]

print(u)

['sheep1', 'sheep2', 'tiger1', 'sheep3', 'hippo1', 'tiger2']
```

*note that, if your strings can have a numeric suffix, this would not be sufficient to cover all cases (e.g. `['alpha']*11+['alpha1']` would repeat `'alpha11'`)*

Comment: This works for me.  Good point about existing numeric suffixes - I shouldn't have any but I'll add an underscore before my count to ensure it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
l = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'tiger', 'sheep', 'hippo', 'tiger']

count = {}
output = []
for s in l:
    if s in count:
        count[s] += 1
    else:
        count[s] = 1

    output.append(f'{s}{count[s]}')

output
```

output:

```
['sheep1', 'sheep2', 'tiger1', 'sheep3', 'hippo1', 'tiger2']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `defaultdict` and `count`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import count
>>> s = ["sheep", "sheep", "tiger", "sheep", "hippo", "tiger"]
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: count(1))
>>> [f'{x}{next(d[x])}' for x in s]
['sheep1', 'sheep2', 'tiger1', 'sheep3', 'hippo1', 'tiger2']
```

`count` is an object that yields ever-increasing numbers as you iterate over it; calling `next` gives you the next number in the sequence.

The `defaultdict` creates a new `count` instance every time you try to access a new key, while saving the newly created instance for the next time you see the same key.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar need where the output would be:

```
['sheep', 'sheep1', 'tiger', 'sheep2', 'hippo', 'tiger1']
```

I approached it a little differently looking for an O(n) solution and extended the dictionary class.

```
class IncDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self,key):
        return -1

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        val = dict.__getitem__(self,key)
        val+=1
        dict.__setitem__(self,key,val)
        if val==0:
            return key
        else:
            return key+str(val)

l = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'tiger', 'sheep', 'hippo', 'tiger']
uniquify = IncDict()
[uniquify[x] for x in l]
```

Output:

```
['sheep', 'sheep1', 'tiger', 'sheep2', 'hippo', 'tiger1']
```